# geting a new sorted list from a list, i only need x items and dont want to sort the whole list before getting the top items

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a class

```
public class Entity : IComparable<Entity>
{

    public float Priority { get; set; }

{
```

I create a list and fill it with Y items that are in no particular order

```
list <Entity> = get_unorderd_list();
```

now i want to sort the list according to the Priority value , but I only care about getting the highest X items in the right order, for performance reasons I don't want to use a regular .sort() method as X is a lot smaller then Y.

Should I write a custom sorting method? Or is there a way to do this?

edit:not talking about geting a single velue by using .max()

Comment: did you mean MAX with highest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I write a custom sorting method?

I don't know of a way of doing it easily from .NET itself. When I [implemented sorting for Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/07/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26d-fixing-the-key-selectors-and-yielding-early.aspx), I took this sort of approach - the whole ordering is a quick-sort, but I only sort as much as I need to in order to return the results so far.

Now, that's still a general approach - if you know how many results you need *beforehand*, you can probably do a lot better. You might want to build a heap-based solution, where you have a bounded heap (max size X) and then iterate over your input, adding values into your heap as you go. As soon as you've filled up the first X elements, you can start discarding new ones which are smaller than your smallest heap  element, without even looking at the rest of the tree. For other elements, you perform the normal operations to insert the element, maintaining the ordering within the heap.

See the [Wikipedia article on binary heaps stored as arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation) for more information about how you might structure your heap.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean MAX simply use linq Max to find highest priority item.you can not write more efficient method than Max,cause you must compare all items in the list to find max Anyway.

```
var highestPeriorityItem = unorderd_list.Max(x=>x.Periority);
```

**EDIT:**

there is another way more efficient than this , that is keeping list sorted from very beginning.that mean you must keep list sorted with each insert(insert item in sorted order). this way time complexity of finding max item is `O(1)` and time complexity of inserting new item is `O(1) < x < O(N)`.

hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution is good as well, and more within my ability as a programmer at the moment, but the answer Jon gave is more directly relevant to what I asked about.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is the last item in your unsorted list could be the highest item in X so you will have to iterate over the whole of Y i should think.